# Exception handling the right way

Tags: php, exception

I have a rather simple question, I just read articles about error and Exception handling in PHP, but I have still some questions left unawnsered.

**1)** In which way is it good to make custom Exception classes (that extend PHP's default Exception)? And in which cases should I make custom exceptions?

**2)** I read that exceptions have to be caught with a catch/try block, but I often see thrown exceptions in codes without any try/catch blocks. Are they using the `set_exception_handler()` function? And how should I use this function properly?

**3)** To allow custom behaviors when an Exception is thrown (For example, record all the Exceptions in a database), should I use `set_exception_handler()` or something else?

Thank you for taking the time to read my questions and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need exceptions that do more than the built-in exceptions then extending them would be the way to go. There is not much more to it than that.
2. They do not *have to* be caught. They *should* be caught at some point (see 3.) but if you are writing a library or module of some kind then you can just throw exceptions and leave it up to the the user of that code to catch it.
3. You can wrap your entire application in a `try-catch` block and then catch any exceptions there, and then do what you need to do with them (e.g. save them to log file, or a database for that matter).

I would personally avoid using `set_exception_handler` (using 3. would be preferable, in my opinion), but in some cases it may be a good, or even the only, solution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick awnser! So, why is 'set_exception_handler' to avoid? Because wrapping the app in a 'try/catch' block would work, but it would do the Exception handling outisde the app, which I feel isn't really good of a solution. So should I do a custom Exception class that could log the exceptions? Thank you!